# JAVA_HOME environment variable and installed Java in CentOS

Tags: java, centos, environment-variables, subversion-edge

I am installing SUbversion Edge under CentOS 7.

The first step is

```
  Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, and point it to your Java 6 JRE
  home.  For example:

  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

  Test the variable:

  $ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
  java version "1.6.0_20"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The problem is that `/usr/java` forlder not exists.

But `/usr/bin/java` is existing.

Have I use this folder instead?
So what do I have to do?

Comment: "forlder" not exists but is existing? what?

Comment: @eis Sorry. I just corrected my text.

Comment: how did you installed java on your centos? it should be in /usr/lib/java* or /usr/lib/jvm* if installing via YUM, also centos has alternatives mechanism, allowing you to have several versions of java on same linux

Comment: @antonu17 I have installed it using `yum`. I am not sure which env. variable and path I have to use... Yeah... There is `usr/lib/jvm` but it has inside different folders... `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default` ends with default and I am not sure what is expectiong...

Comment: Ok, so you shoud not interpret instruction as final statement. It ask you to set JAVA_HOME environment variable, _For example_: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default. You have to set it to correct path in your system. For centos it should be `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre`

Comment: can you attach the output of this command in your system `ls /usr/lib/jvm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correct Java home path in your system. If you installed Java in CentOS via YUM, then correct path should be

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre`

You should not use /usr/bin/java as JAVA_HOME, because it is not Java home path, it is symlink to java executable.